# Unable to connect to database due to driver

Tags: database, groovy

I'm trying to connect to a database using Groovy and can't.
The same error pops up even though i've tried a few things.
The error is "No such property: driver for class".
I known the connection works as i have tried it on the DBeaver app without issues.
The code is as follows:

```
package com.database


//import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.ResultSet
import com.google.api.client.util.Data
import com.kms.katalon.core.annotation.Keyword
//import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection
//import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement
import groovy.sql.Sql
import java.sql.Driver

import groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader
import org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader

import java.sql.Connection
import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.ResultSet
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData
import java.sql.SQLException
import java.sql.Statement
import groovy.sql.Sql

import com.kms.katalon.core.annotation.Keyword
import groovy.sql.*

public class mySql {


@Keyword

  def connectDB(String username, String environment, String url, String port, String dbname, String password){

        //* Attempts:

       //@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
      //@Grab('mysql:mysql-connector-java:S5.1.27')

       // Data Source = MyOracleDB;

      //SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host)(PORT=port))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));uid=username;pwd=password;

      // Class.forName(driver);
     // Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connect, username, password);
    // Statement statement = con.createStatement();



         String connect = username+"@//srv" +environment + url + ":" + port + "/" + dbname

         if(connection != null && !connection.isClosed()){

               connection.close()

         }

         def connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connect, username, password)
             return connection
}
```

If anyone can help would apreciate it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is much simpler than your code suggests. You can still build a string for the newInstance(). Not in a class for simplicity in my example.

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

def myDB = Sql.newInstance('jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.7:3306/employees', 'user1', 'pass1', 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver')

myDB.eachRow("select first_name, last_name from employees.employees;"){
    println "${it.first_name} ${it.last_name}"
}

myDB.close()
```